# pen sdk SpenSurfaceView initiate androidruntime error

Tags: android, samsung-mobile-sdk, stylus-pen

I'm trying to use the samsung spen sdk `pen-v5.1.0_full.aar`. The .aar file is put under /libs and added to the dependencies in `build.gradle` file.

I can initiate the spen fine (from `com.samsung.android.sdk.pen.Spen`),

I can also initiate a `SpenPenDetachmentListener` (from `com.samsung.android.sdk.pen.engine.SpenPenDetachmentListener`),

however, when initiating `SpenSurfaceView` (from `com.samsung.android.sdk.pen.engine.SpenSurfaceView`), I get an AndroidRunTime error:

```
02-11 16:30:03.921 25242 25242 E art     : No implementation found for boolean com.samsung.android.sdk.pen.engine.SpenGLInView.Native_isSupported() (tried Java_com_samsung_android_sdk_pen_engine_SpenGLInView_Native_1isSupported and Java_com_samsung_android_sdk_pen_engine_SpenGLInView_Native_1isSupported__)
02-11 16:30:03.922 25242 25242 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for boolean com.samsung.android.sdk.pen.engine.SpenGLInView.Native_isSupported() (tried Java_com_samsung_android_sdk_pen_engine_SpenGLInView_Native_1isSupported and Java_com_samsung_android_sdk_pen_engine_SpenGLInView_Native_1isSupported__)
02-11 16:30:03.922 25242 25242 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.samsung.android.sdk.pen.engine.SpenGLInView.Native_isSupported(Native Method)
02-11 16:30:03.922 25242 25242 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.samsung.android.sdk.pen.engine.SpenGLInView.isSupported(SpenGLInView.java:6619)
02-11 16:30:03.922 25242 25242 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.samsung.android.sdk.pen.engine.SpenSurfaceView.construct(SpenSurfaceView.java:365)
02-11 16:30:03.922 25242 25242 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.samsung.android.sdk.pen.engine.SpenSurfaceView.<init>(SpenSurfaceView.java:277)
```

I suspect that it's something I did wrong with import / using the .aar sdk, yet I don't understand why the Spen and the PenDetachmentListener can initiate fine yet the SpenSurfaceView not.

The apk compiles OK and would only crash when something tries to initiate the SpenSurfaceView.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that, `SpenSurfaceView` expect that `Spen` is initiated. After initiating `Spen` first, `SpenSurfaceView` is initiating fine.